# право изменения файла .htaccess только с определенного ip

Tags: .htaccess

какой ip адрес просить у операторов связи чтобы заходить как админ на сайт с разных телефонов планшетов и компьютеров но с одной симки и если ее потерял можно было востановить другую сим карту данного оператора но с тем же ip. и как это прописать в файле .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

При каждом входе в интернет с телефона Ваш ip-адрес меняется. А так же в некоторых случаях может меняться и во время пользования. 
Для того, чтобы установить подобное подключение, как описано, Вам необходимо:
 1. Установить услугу статический(Фиксированный за сим) ip-адрес у Вашего провайдера. (Услуга обычно платная) При перестановки сим в другое устройство - ip сохранится. (MAC будет соответственно другой, так как это адрес устройства, но Вам это не помешает)
 2. При восстановлении сим-карты далеко не факт, что за Вами сохранится именно этот ip-адрес, хотя данная услуга у Вас будет оплачена. Вам могут предоставить просто другой ip, как это случилось у меня. 
 3. Для того, чтобы обеспечить доступ к Вашему ресурсу через .htaccess, Вам необходимо прописать в нём свой полученный, статический ip.
 Пример:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.0.0  //Ограничить всем кроме Тут указываете Ваш адрес
Allow from .localnet    // Ограничить всем кроме DNS имя которых содержит .localnet
Allow from admin.net // Ограничить всем кроме хоста, DNS имя которого admin.net
```